# Change the save location

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I'm using below code to save the pdf in my MVC Razor.

```
kendo.drawing.drawDOM($("#testDiv")).then(function(group)
{

        group.options.set("pdf", {            
            margin: {
                left: "10mm",
                top: "20mm",
                right: "10mm",
                bottom: "20mm"
            }
        });
        debugger;
        kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "save.pdf");
    });
```

Question:Is it possible to save the file(pdf) in server ?
Any help is most appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

`kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group,"save.pdf");` will push the file to client's machine.

Try this one, for storing it in server.

```
void savetoServer()
{
       StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(stringBuilder);
        HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(writer);
        try {
            testDiv.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
        } catch (HttpException generatedExceptionName) {
        }


        var fileContents = stringBuilder.ToString();
        var fileName = string.Format("drawing{0}.pdf", "[Your custom file name]");
        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Pdfs/"), Path.GetFileName(fileName)); 

       //in above line "Pdfs" will map to the folder in your application root folder.

        File.WriteAllBytes(path,fileContents);
}
```

Comment: Hi Balaji, 
Thank you for reply. In my question "#testDiv" is an ID of an div. I'm converting the div data into PDF. My question is how to pass entire div data to the server and save in specified server location.

Comment: @NareshReddy `testDiv.RenderControl(htmlWriter); ` will convert the text to plain string, but if you need the exact styles including images and tables of a div. You can make use of iTextSharp library, include it in your application. you can find a tutorial and dll file in this link, this will definitely solve your problem http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-HTML-DIV-contents-to-PDF-using-iTextSharp-in-ASPNet.aspx